# Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/xml;charset="utf-8"' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'

Tags: php, xml, curl

I Called a soap service which was developed in c# and I am implementing it in MY PHP code, I am getting this error "HTTP/1.1 415 Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/xml;charset="utf-8"' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'.".

Please help me how can I resolve this issue?

Here is my code.

```
    <?php
    $xml_string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Invoice xmlns:ubltr="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:TurkishCustomizationExtensionComponents" xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2" xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2" xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2 UBL-Invoice-2.1.xsd" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2">
        <ext:UBLExtensions>
          <ext:UBLExtension>
            <ext:ExtensionContent><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="Signature_INN2020000004738">
      <ds:SignedInfo>
      <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
      <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
      <ds:Reference Id="Reference-Id-fbfd9b87-0852-47e8-9fe0-43967645102c" URI="#Signed-Properties-Id-ff550d10-a81d-4ce5-943c-89d50061cc19" Type="http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties">
      <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
      <ds:DigestValue>G3wTvli8QJrLgjxMLCkK1c7MGjzmTMwKVSzvHMg9Odg=</ds:DigestValue>
      </ds:Reference>
      <ds:Reference Id="Reference-Id-3f25e0e0-2e7e-462c-8b9e-7b73bc6c7119" URI="">
      <ds:Transforms>
      <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
      </ds:Transforms>
      <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
      <ds:DigestValue>StpFdOkLqURx7QnNqftBTzlDBL2isDBD10av/ttVTL0=</ds:DigestValue>
      </ds:Reference>
      </ds:SignedInfo>
      <ds:SignatureValue Id="Signature-Value-Id-7823ee32-b522-4b0a-b022-1d49eaa13d7f">qba6lrTyBvJk1nuTGQ9atoJE5F3ku9mwkrradJKZ6YMJX5ccu1VhzS3FfryFBqfJYI1Xqt+uqQ6j7o5N1yI1RHfmL7PNK3mjOU1UBNSMwf3dJPhDxAegwZkwaAx5tTWIu8T/vO3mZQmX7ZJqLzvmw/1bnk1VrswrzewbfjCha5RajIUDV5a/K4hX6b+N9LENta/cPEoTtc76UTQS3QHzPyFc8r1/Te8sPmpRWTdmNIAnye8BHHKMAodRf3hWfgNfwnUwfzBpa3H6DJGGGzjH4EkzR7clN8D3GYKU4V3U3Xi3dBkv9+fZSJMpb5LzceRwGZcNvVINMig57SVt5MEkWg==</ds:SignatureValue>
      <ds:KeyInfo>
      <ds:KeyValue>
      <ds:RSAKeyValue>
      <ds:Modulus>yIBUILxPZ0ZffJGtlAOXP9jBGcf8gfqd4UXMzpFqpMcGXikuoDA1bBrcyXYOJEQyz5irike1cVKBUdiLvtqDVItPoWxGJqP2yumc7nFcUUYwpsTVXFdLQwQNhFCairzjRWLoCyWrMKU81wWc+N/WrdEHIhMzR9IKKcne8J/OswPldWAxNjFJMiVh9pvx0Oi1rKxyCGmQxqaqOY1yY1vSS/J+l4voY44cshN0rq+rYBic2RSZpMVZIxlHGWmNiFHXRXfBPihFtg67BkubZw9IQ6ZlqmtzYARr/d0tcv0GEfGqNILixxbxSnLSZ5zsSVqpq6BVTDxbs7Ho4CeUpkABvw==</ds:Modulus>
      <ds:Exponent>AQAB</ds:Exponent>
      </ds:RSAKeyValue>
      </ds:KeyValue>
      <ds:X509Data>
      <ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
      <ds:X509SubjectName>CN=İNNOVA BİLİŞİM ÇÖZÜMLERİ ANONİM ŞİRKETİ,SERIALNUMBER=4780163831</ds:X509SubjectName>
      </ds:X509Data>
      </ds:KeyInfo>
      <ds:Object Id="Object-Id-885f4d52-fed0-4ad2-b298-93850cdc874c"><xades:QualifyingProperties xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" Target="Signature_INN2020000004738">
      <xades:SignedProperties Id="Signed-Properties-Id-ff550d10-a81d-4ce5-943c-89d50061cc19">
      <xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
      <xades:SigningTime>2020-05-07T12:20:52.0792734+03:00</xades:SigningTime>
      <xades:SigningCertificate>
      <xades:Cert>
      <xades:CertDigest>
      <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
      <ds:DigestValue>VCgHJeCh7rKyUChRRRSEn90raVcNP3pavlk/NifKd9g=</ds:DigestValue>
      </xades:CertDigest>
      <xades:IssuerSerial>
      <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=Mali Mühür Elektronik Sertifika Hizmet Sağlayıcısı - Sürüm 2,C=TR</ds:X509IssuerName>
      <ds:X509SerialNumber>2297718970252027</ds:X509SerialNumber>
      </xades:IssuerSerial>
      </xades:Cert>
      </xades:SigningCertificate>
      </xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
      <xades:SignedDataObjectProperties>
      <xades:DataObjectFormat ObjectReference="#Reference-Id-3f25e0e0-2e7e-462c-8b9e-7b73bc6c7119">
      <xades:MimeType>text/xml</xades:MimeType>
      </xades:DataObjectFormat>
      </xades:SignedDataObjectProperties>
      </xades:SignedProperties>
      </xades:QualifyingProperties>
      </ds:Object>
      </ds:Signature></ext:ExtensionContent>
          </ext:UBLExtension>
        </ext:UBLExtensions>
        <cbc:UBLVersionID>2.1</cbc:UBLVersionID>
        <cbc:CustomizationID>TR1.2</cbc:CustomizationID>
        <cbc:ProfileID>TICARIFATURA</cbc:ProfileID>
        <cbc:ID>INN2020000004738</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:CopyIndicator>false</cbc:CopyIndicator>
        <cbc:UUID>18FF00EA-9F5F-4713-98E6-7E61353DD749</cbc:UUID>
        <cbc:IssueDate>2020-01-08</cbc:IssueDate>
        <cbc:IssueTime>13:00:00.0000000+03:00</cbc:IssueTime>
        <cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>TEVKIFAT</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
        <cbc:Note>YALNIZ  BİN DOKSAN TL SIFIR KURUŞ</cbc:Note>
        <cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode listID="ISO 4217 Alpha" listAgencyName="United Nations Economic Commission for Europe" listName="Currency" listVersionID="2001">TRY</cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>
        <cbc:LineCountNumeric>1</cbc:LineCountNumeric>
        <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
          <cbc:ID>7D09D503-0E91-4CF0-A40D-6D075C8A0DD1</cbc:ID>
          <cbc:IssueDate>2020-01-08</cbc:IssueDate>

        </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cac:Signature>
          <cbc:ID schemeID="VKN_TCKN">4780163831</cbc:ID>
          <cac:SignatoryParty>
            <cbc:WebsiteURI>www.innova.com.tr</cbc:WebsiteURI>
            <cac:PartyIdentification>
              <cbc:ID schemeID="VKN">4780163831</cbc:ID>
            </cac:PartyIdentification>
            <cac:PartyName>
              <cbc:Name>İnnova Bilişim Çözümleri A.Ş.</cbc:Name>
            </cac:PartyName>
            <cac:PostalAddress>
              <cbc:Room>1</cbc:Room>
              <cbc:StreetName>Ayazağa Caddesi</cbc:StreetName>
              <cbc:BuildingName>Arı 4</cbc:BuildingName>
              <cbc:BuildingNumber>2</cbc:BuildingNumber>
              <cbc:CitySubdivisionName>MASLAK</cbc:CitySubdivisionName>
              <cbc:CityName>İSTANBUL</cbc:CityName>
              <cbc:PostalZone>34469</cbc:PostalZone>
              <cac:Country>
                <cbc:Name>Türkiye</cbc:Name>
              </cac:Country>
            </cac:PostalAddress>
          </cac:SignatoryParty>
          <cac:DigitalSignatureAttachment>
            <cac:ExternalReference>
              <cbc:URI>#Signature_INN2020000004738</cbc:URI>
            </cac:ExternalReference>
          </cac:DigitalSignatureAttachment>
        </cac:Signature>
        <cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
          <cac:Party>
            <cbc:WebsiteURI>www.innova.com.tr</cbc:WebsiteURI>
            <cac:PartyIdentification>
              <cbc:ID schemeID="VKN">4780163831</cbc:ID>
            </cac:PartyIdentification>
            <cac:PartyIdentification>
              <cbc:ID schemeID="TICARETSICILNO">231345</cbc:ID>
            </cac:PartyIdentification>
            <cac:PartyIdentification>
              <cbc:ID schemeID="MERSISNO">777777777778</cbc:ID>
            </cac:PartyIdentification>
            <cac:PartyName>
              <cbc:Name>İnnova Bilişim Çözümleri A.Ş.</cbc:Name>
            </cac:PartyName>
            <cac:PostalAddress>
              <cbc:Room>1</cbc:Room>
              <cbc:StreetName>Ayazağa Caddesi</cbc:StreetName>
              <cbc:BuildingName>Arı 4</cbc:BuildingName>
              <cbc:BuildingNumber>2</cbc:BuildingNumber>
              <cbc:CitySubdivisionName>MASLAK</cbc:CitySubdivisionName>
              <cbc:CityName>İSTANBUL</cbc:CityName>
              <cbc:PostalZone>34469</cbc:PostalZone>
              <cac:Country>
                <cbc:Name>Türkiye</cbc:Name>
              </cac:Country>
            </cac:PostalAddress>
            <cac:PartyTaxScheme>
              <cac:TaxScheme>
                <cbc:Name>Boğaziçi Kurumlar Vergi Dairesi</cbc:Name>
              </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:PartyTaxScheme>
            <cac:Contact>
              <cbc:Telephone>2123297000</cbc:Telephone>
              <cbc:Telefax>2122864402</cbc:Telefax>
              <cbc:ElectronicMail>yalkis@innova.com.tr</cbc:ElectronicMail>
            </cac:Contact>
          </cac:Party>
        </cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
        <cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
          <cac:Party>
            <cac:PartyIdentification>
              <cbc:ID schemeID="VKN">4780163831</cbc:ID>
            </cac:PartyIdentification>
            <cac:PartyName>
              <cbc:Name>İnnova Bilişim Çözümleri A.Ş.</cbc:Name>
            </cac:PartyName>
            <cac:PostalAddress>
              <cbc:CitySubdivisionName>Semt/İlçe</cbc:CitySubdivisionName>
              <cbc:CityName>Şehir</cbc:CityName>
              <cbc:PostalZone />
              <cbc:Region>Semt/İlçe</cbc:Region>
              <cac:Country>
                <cbc:Name>Ülke</cbc:Name>
              </cac:Country>
            </cac:PostalAddress>
            <cac:PartyTaxScheme>
              <cac:TaxScheme>
                <cbc:Name>Vergi Dairesi</cbc:Name>
              </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:PartyTaxScheme>
            <cac:Contact>
              <cbc:ElectronicMail>yalkis@innova.com.tr</cbc:ElectronicMail>
            </cac:Contact>
          </cac:Party>
        </cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
        <cac:AllowanceCharge>
          <cbc:ChargeIndicator>false</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
          <cbc:MultiplierFactorNumeric>0</cbc:MultiplierFactorNumeric>
          <cbc:SequenceNumeric>1</cbc:SequenceNumeric>
          <cbc:Amount currencyID="TRY">0.00</cbc:Amount>
        </cac:AllowanceCharge>
        <cac:TaxTotal>
          <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="TRY">90.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
          <cac:TaxSubtotal>
            <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="TRY">1000.00</cbc:TaxableAmount>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="TRY">180.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
            <cbc:CalculationSequenceNumeric>1</cbc:CalculationSequenceNumeric>
            <cbc:Percent>18</cbc:Percent>
            <cac:TaxCategory>
              <cac:TaxScheme>
                <cbc:Name>KDV</cbc:Name>
                <cbc:TaxTypeCode>0015</cbc:TaxTypeCode>
              </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:TaxCategory>
          </cac:TaxSubtotal>
        </cac:TaxTotal>
        <cac:WithholdingTaxTotal>
          <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="TRY">90.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
          <cac:TaxSubtotal>
            <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="TRY">180.00</cbc:TaxableAmount>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="TRY">90.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
            <cbc:CalculationSequenceNumeric>1</cbc:CalculationSequenceNumeric>
            <cbc:Percent>50</cbc:Percent>
            <cac:TaxCategory>
              <cac:TaxScheme>
                <cbc:Name>Yemek servis hizmeti</cbc:Name>
                <cbc:TaxTypeCode>604</cbc:TaxTypeCode>
              </cac:TaxScheme>
            </cac:TaxCategory>
          </cac:TaxSubtotal>
        </cac:WithholdingTaxTotal>
        <cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
          <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="TRY">1000.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
          <cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount currencyID="TRY">1000.00</cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount>
          <cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount currencyID="TRY">1180.00</cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount>
          <cbc:AllowanceTotalAmount currencyID="TRY">0.00</cbc:AllowanceTotalAmount>
          <cbc:ChargeTotalAmount currencyID="TRY">0.00</cbc:ChargeTotalAmount>
          <cbc:PayableAmount currencyID="TRY">1090.00</cbc:PayableAmount>
        </cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
        <cac:InvoiceLine>
          <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>
          <cbc:Note />
          <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="NIU">1</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
          <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="TRY">1000.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
          <cac:AllowanceCharge>
            <cbc:ChargeIndicator>false</cbc:ChargeIndicator>
            <cbc:MultiplierFactorNumeric>0</cbc:MultiplierFactorNumeric>
            <cbc:SequenceNumeric>1</cbc:SequenceNumeric>
            <cbc:Amount currencyID="TRY">0.00</cbc:Amount>
            <cbc:BaseAmount currencyID="TRY">1000</cbc:BaseAmount>
          </cac:AllowanceCharge>
          <cac:TaxTotal>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="TRY">90.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
            <cac:TaxSubtotal>
              <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="TRY">1000.00</cbc:TaxableAmount>
              <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="TRY">180.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
              <cbc:CalculationSequenceNumeric>1</cbc:CalculationSequenceNumeric>
              <cbc:Percent>18</cbc:Percent>
              <cac:TaxCategory>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                  <cbc:Name>KDV</cbc:Name>
                  <cbc:TaxTypeCode>0015</cbc:TaxTypeCode>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
              </cac:TaxCategory>
            </cac:TaxSubtotal>
          </cac:TaxTotal>
          <cac:WithholdingTaxTotal>
            <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="TRY">90.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
            <cac:TaxSubtotal>
              <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="TRY">180.00</cbc:TaxableAmount>
              <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="TRY">90.00</cbc:TaxAmount>
              <cbc:CalculationSequenceNumeric>1</cbc:CalculationSequenceNumeric>
              <cbc:Percent>50</cbc:Percent>
              <cac:TaxCategory>
                <cac:TaxScheme>
                  <cbc:Name>Yemek servis hizmeti</cbc:Name>
                  <cbc:TaxTypeCode>604</cbc:TaxTypeCode>
                </cac:TaxScheme>
              </cac:TaxCategory>
            </cac:TaxSubtotal>
          </cac:WithholdingTaxTotal>
          <cac:Item>
            <cbc:Name>Sadece Tevkifat</cbc:Name>
          </cac:Item>
          <cac:Price>
            <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="TRY">1000</cbc:PriceAmount>
          </cac:Price>
        </cac:InvoiceLine>
      </Invoice>';


    //$Row['templateType'] = 'salesOrder';
    $invoiceName = 'SO12345.xml';

    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
    $dom->loadXML($xml_string);                

    //$basePath = UPLOAD_PATH . 'attachments/';
    //$file_url = $basePath . $invoiceName; 
    //Save XML as a file
    //$dom->save($file_url);  

    $username = 'wahmet';
    $password = '123+Test';

    $url = 'https://efaturatest.innova.com.tr/ClientInterfaceService?singlewsdl';
    $headers = array(
    "Content-type:  application/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
    "Accept: application/xml",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Pragma: no-cache",
    'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode($username.':'.$password),
    );
    $CURL = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, base64_encode($xml_string)); 
    curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    //curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

    $xmlResponse = curl_exec($CURL); 

    $curlInfo = curl_getinfo($CURL, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

      $errors = curl_error($CURL);

        var_dump($xmlResponse);
        //echo 'info=';print_r($curlInfo);
        //echo 'error=';print_r($errors);exit;

        curl_close ($CURL);               
        ?>
        Response:
        "HTTP/1.1 415 Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/xml;charset="utf-8"' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'. Content-Length: 0 Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 Date: Fri, 29 May 2020 09:33:42 GMT "
```

Answer (score 1):

As `text/xml;charset=utf-8` is the Content-Type expected by the server, you should replace :

```
"Content-type:  application/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
```

by :

```
"Content-type:  text/xml;charset=utf-8",
```

in the curl request headers.

Comment: Hi Nicom
we are getting this error now

HTTP/1.1 100 Continue HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Content-Length: 0 Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 Date: Sat, 30 May 2020 06:41:22 GMT info=400error=

Comment: Hello, 400 HTTP errors are about bad request. The request is validated on server side and it will respond with a 400 error if something in the request doesn’t match the expected format or data types. So in order to fix it, you need to compare server’s  expected request schema and your request body.